# Inter document similarity(cosine similarity)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program to find the similarity between 2 files of document.
For this reason, I am following [this](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=1747) link and a posting [from](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2013/05/inter-document-similarity-with-scikit.html)

But, an error is shown up which says

```
"list object is not callable"
```

at

```
test(tf_idf_matrix,count,nltkutil.cosine_distance)
```

line.

I am using one file as train set and other file as test set and my objective is to use the `test()` to output the cosine similarity between 2 documents using tf-idf.

My code is following:

```
def test(tdMatrix,count,fsim):

    sims=[] 
    sims = np.zeros((len(tdMatrix), count))

    for i in range(len(tdMatrix)):
        for j in range(count):
                doc1 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[tdMatrix[i], :].todense()).reshape(-1)
                doc2 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[tdMatrix[j], :].todense()).reshape(-1)

                sims[i, j] = fsim(doc1, doc2)

            print sims

def main():

    file_set=["corpusA.txt","corpusB.txt"]
    train=[]
    test=[]

    for file1 in file_set:
        s="x"+file1
        preprocess(file1,s)

    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    m=open("xcorpusA.txt",'r')
    for i in m:
        train.append(i.strip())
    #print doc
    count_vectorizer.fit_transform(train)


    m1=open("xcorpusB.txt",'r')
    for i in m1:
        test.append(i.strip())

    freq_term_matrix = count_vectorizer.transform(test)
    #print freq_term_matrix.todense()

    tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
    tfidf.fit(freq_term_matrix)

    #print "IDF:", tfidf.idf_

    tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(freq_term_matrix)
    print (tf_idf_matrix.toarray())

    count=0

    for i in tf_idf_matrix.toarray():
        for j in i:
            count+=1    
        break

    print "Results with Cosine Distance Similarity Measure"
    test(tf_idf_matrix,count,nltkutil.cosine_distance)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In the future, please refer to http://sscce.org. Much of the code you posted is irrelevant to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()` you define a list named `test`:

```
test=[]
```

This list shadows the function named `test()` you define outside `main()`, so when you try:

```
test(tf_idf_matrix,count,nltkutil.cosine_distance)
```

Python attempts to *call the list* with the supplied arguments. Inevitably, you get a `TypeError`.

To fix this, rename either the list, the function, or (ideally) both with names that more clearly describe what they are for.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I try to find out the cosine similarity between 2 files and still not getting way to make it. Thank you for pointing out the error. But still the code did not work. I modified my question so that mentors can check my code.

Comment: You have changed the question such that my answer is no longer correct. If you have a new problem, that should be a separate question.

Comment: @jonrshape: I am deleting the post and posting a new question. Thank You

Comment: You have just replaced this question again. Leave this question as it was, and ask a completely new one.

Comment: I replaced the question as "Inter Document Similarity: Cosine distance" I am looking for any advice/suggestion.